# General Formula for the number of positive integers with n digits in which adjacent digits differ by at most 1

Tags: combinatorics

I was recently posed the question 'What is the number of positive 6 digit integers in which adjacent digits differ by at most 1', I was able to solve the question but couldn't figure out how to come up with a general formula for any n.

For increasing n the solutions are : 9, 26, 75, 217, 629, 1826, 5307, 15438, 44941, 130900, 381444, 1111926, 3242224, 9455987 ...

So could you provide a proof for the general formula of this sequence?

Comment: OEIS has a recurrence thats easy to derive and corresponding generating function: [A235163](https://oeis.org/A235163).

Comment: what does this formula mean '-x*(3*x^4-18*x^3-9*x^2+28*x-9)/(x^5-6*x^4-x^3+10*x^2-6*x+1)' as it tends to -3 as x gets large, and I already knew about the recursive relationship as it's how I solved for the case n=6, I was looking for a formula for a(n) in terms of n if that's possible.

Comment: Its a generating function. See H. Wilf's Generatingfunctionology for details (available for free [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)). I doubt there is something nicer than whats given on OEIS given how that generating function looks. Basically, you expand that function into its  series about 0 and the n-th coefficient determines the n-th value of the sequence.

Comment: Arr, I see thank you for the response :D

Comment: May I ask what makes it such that some sequences cannot make explicit general formula's in terms of n?